# プロダクション環境のパッケージアップデートのベストプラクティスは？

Tags: linux, yum, apt

linux 系のプロダクション環境にサーバーをデプロイしていたとします。このサーバー上の、パッケージアップデートはどのように行うのがよいのでしょうか？

というのも、 linux 系の OS においては、 yum か apt 系のパッケージマネージャーによってソフトウェアが管理されています。これらパッケージは、放っておくとすぐに新しいパッケージがリリースされ、そのままそれらを放置しておくのは、よろしくないと考えます。

ふと考えるのは、古いパッケージを使うのがよくないならば、例えば cron でパッケージアップグレードしてしまってもよさそうです。しかし、これは本当に理想ならば、むしろ標準の system cron あたりでこの機構は実装されていても良さそうな気がします。

#### 質問

- linux 系 OS におけるプロダクション環境において、パッケージアップデートはどう対応するのがよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yumなら`yum-cron`、aptも`cron-apt`というそのものずばりな仕組みが用意されており、適切に設定を行えばパッケージの自動更新は一応可能ではあります。

ただし「プロダクション環境で事前検証なしにアップデートを適用していいのか？」については個人・組織の運用ポリシー次第ですので、必要であれば「重要なセキュリティフィックスのみ自動更新」という設定もできます。
詳しくはそれぞれのマニュアル等を参照してみてください。